# Is it possible to drive a 2 X 16 LCD display using logic gates? (Without computer)

Tags: lcd, logic-gates, programming

I want to make a circuit using logic gates that prints a message on the LCD display (2 X 16). Any  idea? I want to know how to do this "by hand". like the old days.

Can I build a circuit out of logic gates hooked up to a keyboard that when I press a key the character is displayed on the LCD?

Comment: If you're talking about HD44780-based displays, they were never driven "by hand",  they were designed for Motorola MCU bus. It's not impossible of course, but neither is herding cats.

Comment: Can I build a circuit out of logic gates hooked up  to a keyboad that when I press a key the character is displayed on the LCD?

Comment: Like I said, yes, it's possible.

Comment: You can build a CPU with logic gates. See [big mess o'wires](https://www.bigmessowires.com/bmow1/) for a crazy example. So, yes, you can drive a 2x16 LCD too. Be aware, though, that it will take you probably a few weeks. And there are probably more interesting things to do with this time (I'm not judging, but still judging a bit...).

Comment: Re, "Without computer."  I guess that depends on what you think "computer" means.  I have worked with more than one "computer" in the past that had no microprocessor whatsoever.  There was nothing in the box but a big old bunch of logic gates that were connected together in such a way that they fetched instructions and operands from memory, decoded the instructions, peformed them, wrote results back out to memory---just like what a _real_ computer would do.  https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8278/8942466121_db0327bc2e_b.jpg

Comment: You can do it in Minecraft: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQqWorbrAaY

Comment: In the "old days", there was no such thing as a 2x16 LCD with a built in controller, driver, and handy 8-bit bus.  What you are proposing is a bit like trying to build an automobile computer for a fuel-injected engine out of relays and vacuum tubes.  Nobody ever did it that way - old cars had carburetors and no computers at all.  A 2x16 LCD panel is **designed** to be operated via a microcontroller.  If you want an oldschool project, go pick up some 7-segment BCD indicators and start from there.

Comment: I thik connecting to a PS/2 or USB keyboard would be more challenging than driving a 2x16 LCD.  If I had to do it with logic other than a micro I would look first at a few parallel ROM (Flash)  chips and come counters to build some state machines. GALs and FPGAs could help, insisting on a x.y matrix keyboard might be needed.  Discreet logic will be a lot of work but not impossible.

Answer (score 16):

It is possible to make a circuit out of logic gates that would be able to initialize and display characters onto a 16x2 LCD character mode module. It is also possible to make a circuit out of logic gates that could take the output of a standard matrix keypad or even a PS2 type keyboard and route that keyboard data to the LCD module.

The big thing to think about though is that in just asking the question you imply that you are at the beginning of the learning curve of how to go about doing a project like this. I suggest that if you want to build something out of logic gates that you start with something a lot simpler till you get the idea of what is involved in putting together things to make this type if thing. Only then will you begin to be able to answer your own question as to why it may not make much sense to connect a keypad and an LCD module with dedicated logic gates. It would take a good amount of logic gates to achieve this and certainly a lot of time and effort to come to a good result. Once you had it all completed you would almost immediately begin thinking about how you could make the display show a string of characters and possibly even have ability to "edit" the displayed string. Now the logic gate implementation becomes a nightmare of a whole new project.

So there is a reason that the whole world has transitioned to doing things like this with a microcontroller. Very simple interfaces are used to connect things like matrix keypads and 16x2 LCD modules to the GPIO interfaces of the microcontroller. These simple interfaces are easy to build and test to make sure that they work. Once in place it becomes a simple software job to provide the logical connectivity between the keypad and the LCD module. And that software can be as simple as the original design scenario that you asked about to just take a single input from the keypad and show it on the display or it can be adapted to show almost anything on the display ... for example showing a count if how many times a key has been pressed ... or show how long a key has been pressed ... or show a whole user interface that operates your device.

Comment: It is possible to make a circuit out of logic gates that is a computer, for that matter :-)

Comment: @JardelB. on StackExchange network, if an answer helped you the most you _accept_ it by clicking a check mark on the left of it. This act automatically thanks the author by adding him some positive reputation.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  You'll need several blocks to make it work:

1. You need an LCD driving block.  The LCD is intended to be written to in 4 bit or 8 bit mode, I recommend 8 bit for this application.  Each write involves putting the data on the bus and twiddling the E line. For this system you only need to write to the LCD so the RD/WR lines can be wired high or low to put the display in write mode.
2. You need to initialize the LCD once on power up, which involves sending a series of bytes to it. This will involve memory of some sort, whether a diode matrix, or a rom. On power up a counter will have to send sequential addresses to the "memory" whose output will be routed to the LCD driving block.
3. You need a keyboard reading block.  I suggest you use a PS2 keyboard interface if you want to use a PC style keyboard, however you can build your own button bank and scanning system if you want.  If using PS2 you'll have to generate a clock and read serial data, then convert it into parallel data.
4. You need a keyboard conversion block.  This will take the keyboard code and convert it into a character the LCD can display. This will involve memory similar to the initialization block, but you'll need at least one memory cell for each key, requiring a very large diode matrix, or a ROM. If you are clever about it, you can use one ROM for both functions.

As others have pointed out, this is all non-trivial, and will require many logic chips for each section.  However it can be done, and when you succeed you'll have completed a very hard project.

Comment: If you expand the definition of logic gates to virtual gates in an FPGA, it wouldn't be hard. You can find prewritten HDL blocks for PS/2 in and HD44780 out, or even VGA out.

Answer (score 3):

Let me add another take on this. If you really do want to learn what it takes from a logic view point to interface a keypad to an LCD module with specific dedicated logic design then I can say a number of things....

1. It is always great thing to be able to learn how to do things at the nuts and bolts level. Things learned this way will stay with you for a lifetime.
2. Rather than approach this with the idea to build up a glob of wires and logic gates look around on eBay for a used FPGA evaluation board that has a keypad and an LCD module on it. These will be connected to the FPGA pins. You can then learn all you want about the logic design process using the FPGA design resources to make the functionality that you want.
3. You will quickly find that almost all folks that use an FPGA evaluation board of the type I described above will design their system to include a "soft core" microcontroller into the FPGA that then runs a software algorithm to operate the keypad and the LCD module interfaces!!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, but you would need an awful lot of them!

A useful resource might be Code by [Charles Petzold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Petzold). He talks about it in his interview [here](https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/feature/-/13004/102-1065488-6486457).

This book begins by looking at how you can transmit information in a single bit, then two bits (i.e. one if by land, two if by sea), then more. Then looks at logic and how gates might be implemented with relays, then moves onto more and more complex building blocks like flip-flops and adders. You will find how to implement delays, dividers, multiplexers, memory, basically everything you would need. If there's a resource that starts from nothing and builds an entire computer "by hand" this is probably it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. It is a fairly complex task - even if you implemented it in FPGA, it would likely take weeks rather than days.

I question what you will learn from a project of this complexity above your experience of doing the same with an mcu (or something simpler, or just interfacing the world to your mcu).

Back in about 1986, I built a 'lift simulator' using a couple of 8x8 LED arrays, some counter chips and a massive array of diodes. This taught me a bit about system design, logic minimisation, some state machine concepts, but not a lot about circuit design.

Sure, it made an impressive demo (the school kept it and brought it out to show off at open days), and at the time it was not that far off 'state-of-the-art'.

Doing the same thing today, I'd use an MCU platform (the micro-bit even has the matrix built in), and the task would be software. If I used an FPGA, I'd be writing pretty much the same software in verilog. Using discrete logic or even diode arrays today is teaching yourself obsolete skills (yes, I've built an 144 MHz valve amp, so I appreciate there can sometimes be relevance).

The difference between the lift simulator and the scale of designs I work on today (100k gate, 5-10 my designs) is really the level of abstraction. Break the design down into blocks, model the interactions and get the structure right. The low-level implementation is all about re-using something that's been done before.  The functional design also relies for it's performance on a complex software decompressor to reconstruct the datastream that I generate.

If you limit yourself to only implementing in logic, you miss out on a massive inventive step where software can easily do your work for you (trivial example, sorting a set of configuration address values in ascending order to apply a priority rule. Sure, hardware *can* do it, but the cost in the implementation is non-trivial and also pointless - software using my design can do this for free).

A small amount of compute embedded in a device is now close to free - you can frequently reduce the production cost by adding an mcu (and get more features which may or may not add real value).